# C: Constant length doesn't allow me to declare array

Tags: arrays, c, constants, declaration, variable-length-array

I'm experiencing this annoying issue when I try to compile a simple code to understand pointers.
Basically, the error happens in the declaration of the array:

```
// Use of pointers

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const int SIZE = 5;

    int grades[SIZE]={78, 80, 75, 82, 83};
    //memset( grades, 0, SIZE*sizeof(int) );
    double sum = 0.0;
    double *ptr_sum = &sum;
    int i;

    printf("My grades are: \n");
    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",grades[i]);
        sum = sum + grades[i];
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("My average is %.2f\n\n", sum/SIZE);

    printf("sum is at %p, or %lu and is %lf\n",
        ptr_sum, ptr_sum, *ptr_sum);
    printf("Grades are at %lu to %lu\n", grades, grades+5);
    return 0;
}
```

After trying to compile, the error is the following:

`pointers.c:8:5: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized      int grades[SIZE]={78, 80, 75, 82, 83};`

If I'm using a constant for the length of my array, why is this happening?

If I remove the array content (including the brackets), the program compiles. If I leave the array empty it fails again.

Comment: Unrelated, see the format specification section [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for the proper specifiers to use for things like printing pointer addresses. `%lu` may look like it 'works', but in fact you're lying to printf. You're telling it you're sending an unsigned long, an instead sending a `double *`.

Comment: There's a difference between an _integer constant_ and a _constant integer_.  Horribly subtle, too.  If the dimension of the array is not an integer constant, it counts as a VLA.  `const int SIZE = 5;` is a constant integer, but is not an integer constant.  `enum { SIZE = 5; }` is an integer constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C opposite to C++ using a constant object in a declaration of an array like this.

```
const int SIZE = 5;

int grades[SIZE]={78, 80, 75, 82, 83};
```

declares a variable length array that may not be initialized in its declaration.

Instead you need to use an integral constant expression.

From the C Standard (6.6 Constant expressions).

> 6 An integer constant expression117) shall have integer type and shall
> only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants,
> character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer
> constants, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of
> casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only
> convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an
> operand to the sizeof operator.

In this quote the term `"integer constants"` means integer literals not objects declared with the qualifier `const`.

You can declare the array for example the following way.

```
enum { SIZE = 5 };

int grades[SIZE]={78, 80, 75, 82, 83};

//...
```

Or alternatively you can introduce a macro like.

```
#define SIZE 5

//...

int grades[SIZE]={78, 80, 75, 82, 83};

//...
```

Or you could at first declare the array without specifying its size and then introduce the constant that specifiers its size as for example

```
int grades[]={78, 80, 75, 82, 83};
const size_t SIZE = sizeof( grades ) / sizeof( *grades );
```

Also these call of `printf`.

```
printf("sum is at %p, or %lu and is %lf\n",
    ptr_sum, ptr_sum, *ptr_sum);

printf("Grades are at %lu to %lu\n", grades, grades+5);
```

Are incorrect. You are trying to output a pointer using the conversion specifier `lu`. You need to use the conversion specifier `p`.
For example

```
printf("Grades are at %p to %p\n", ( void * )grades, ( void * )( grades+SIZE ));
```

Comment: Why not just `int grades[]={78, 80, 75, 82, 83};`?

Comment: @PaulSanders I am considering the presented code and its problem and how to resolve it using the provided approach.

Comment: Not sure how it works. After I `printf("%p", *ptr_grade)` (using the formatting you suggest), I would expect the program to print the sum of the array in dec, but instead I get 00000000. Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

Comment: @NicolásRivera What is ptr_grade? If it is a pointer then the expression *ptr_grade has the type int.  Outputting an integer using the conversion specifier $p results in undefined behavior. If you want to output the value stored in the pointer then you need to write printf( "%p", ( void * )ptr_grade );

Comment: Also (sorry, I'm very new in C), why do you write `void` when printing the pointer of `grades`?
Furthermore, the result of 
`printf("Grades are at %p to %p\n",  (void*)grades, (void*)grades+SIZE);`
makes more sense than what you do: In your case the byte-difference is 20, here it's only 5, which makes more sense, since the size of the array is 5, as explained by you.

Comment: @NicolásRivera The type void is incomplete type. So you may not use the pointer arithmetic with the type void *. As for the first question then according to the C Standard " p   The argument shall be a pointer to void"

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I think you should at least mention it as an alternative in your answer.  The OP might not be aware that he / she can do it, and it is usually the best way.

Answer (score 4):

The array is considered a variable length array because its size is not a compile time constant, and a `const` variable doesn't qualify as such.  And because it is a variable length array, it cannot be initialized.

You would need to make `SIZE` a macro so that a direct token substitution is done.

```
#define SIZE 5
```

Answer (score 2):

`const` does not mean "constant". This is admittedly a bit confusing, since the keyword `const` is obviously derived from the English word "constant", but they mean two different things.

In C, `const` means read-only. If an object (variable) is defined with the `const` keyword, that means that its value can't legally be changed after it's been initialized. If you use `SIZE` as an expression, it's not a *constant* expression. So

```
int grades[SIZE];
```

is a variable-length array. A typical compiler will probably generate code equivalent to that for a fixed-length array, but the language rules still apply, including the one that says a variable-length array cannot be initialized.

A *constant expression* is one that must be evaluated at compile time, such as `42` or `2+2`.

Note that, for example, this declaration is perfectly legal:

```
const int r = rand();
```

even though the value of `rand()` can't be determined until the program is executed (assuming the PRNG has been seeded using some run-time value). Making the initializer a constant expression doesn't change the behavior.

(C++ has a special-case rule that `const int SIZE = 5;` does make `SIZE` a constant expression. This is convenient, but in my opinion it's slightly unfortunate. C++'s newer `constexpr` is a better way to do the same thing. But of course C is not C++.)

C unfortunately does not have very good ways to define named constants of arbitrary types. The most common method is to use a preprocessor macro:

```
#define SIZE 5
```

but macro names are not scoped the way ordinary identifiers are. A solution that works only for type `int` is:

```
enum { SIZE = 5 };
```

Either of those will let you declare:

```
int grades[SIZE]={78, 80, 75, 82, 83};
```